# Как спарсить enclosure в XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlparser

```
<enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2016/11/13/15/20161113154421483/pic_c965b5934788de18b47e83d2182ee348.jpg" length="26555" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

Как мне это спарсить и загрузить в listview?

Comment: XmlPullParser использовать принципиально?

Comment: Ну если на нём невозможно, то нет

Comment: А что предпочтительнее использовать?